# $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}\frac{(4x^2+kx+7k-6)}{2x^2-5x-3}$

Tags: limits

Find the value of $k$ for which the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}\frac{(4x^2+kx+7k-6)}{2x^2-5x-3}$$ and find this limit.

Solution:
First I try to simplify the function which I got $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}\frac{(4x^2+kx+7k-6)}{(2x+1)(x-3)}$, in my opinion, the value of $k$ could be any real number for the limit exist.
The limit of $x$ should be $x\neq-1/2$,$x\neq3.$

I just want to know if I'm right or it's wrong.

Comment: Hint: What happen if the numerator can divide $x-3$?

Comment: god,I was doing some matrix early on, and I forgot I am doing limit now.thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **must** be that $\;3\;$ is a root of the numerator's polynomial (why?), so

$$4\cdot 9+3k+7k-6=0\iff 10k=-30\iff k=-3\implies$$

$$4x^2-3x-27=(x-3)(4x+9)$$

the limit then is

$$\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{4x^2-3x-27}{2x^2-5x-3}=\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{\color{red}{(x-3)}(4x+9)}{\color{red}{(x-3)}(2x+1)}=\ldots$$